# Visual Studio Code/Intellisense cannot find Unreal Engine CoreMinimal.h file

Tags: c++, include, unreal-engine5

I was using UE5 with VSCode perfectly fine, and Intellisense and #include were both working fine. But when I made another C++ class in the editor, suddenly my Intellisense stopped working and I was getting red squiggleys under my includes. The code still worked fine but I was annoyed. so I deleted my Intermediate and Binaries folder and tried to rebuild to solve the issue, but it said I had to rebuild from the source. When I checked back, it said it couldn't open "CoreMinimal.h", so I edited the includePath setting to go to where my CoreMinimal.h file was (C:\Users\Username\Documents\My Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public). But when I went back to check my includes, it said it "cannot open source file "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformCompilerPreSetup.h" (dependency of "CoreMinimal.h")".

I tried looking up the issue, but there wasn't much there. The only solution I could find was to Generate Visual Studio Project Files, but that did nothing. I also tried installing a GitHub extension to help this issue, but it hasn't helped either.

I can't even open my UE5 project because of this, would love some help/advice.

I've tried deleting Intermediate, Binaries, and saved folder, but it didn't work, and neither did deleting .vscode and regenerating it. I can't even really find UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformCompilerPreSetup.h in my folders. I'm also not getting the prompt to modify the file and choose to reload all after completion or regenerate the project solution.

Answer (score 3):

What did for me was to refresh visual studio code project from inside U5: `tools -> refresh visual studio code project`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. When VSCode asked for a file location to access my .cpp and .h files, I located it to my project folder where my .uprojects were, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your workspace folder, look for .vscode/compileCommands_Default.json

Add then add your new source code and header there.

```
    {
        "file": "F:\\ind\\your\\path\\to\\new\\source.h",
        "arguments":.... Same as other {} above ....
                 "directory": ... same
    },
    {
        "file": "F:\\ind\\your\\path\\to\\new\\source.cpp",
        "arguments":.... Same as other {} above ....
        "directory": ... same
    }
```